# How to re-encrypt a Whatsapp db file?

Tags: encryption, whatsapp, public-key

A week ago I decrypted a crypt14 WhatsApp database file using [this python script](https://github.com/ElDavoo/WhatsApp-Crypt14-Crypt15-Decrypter). But I accedientally deleted the original crypt14.

Now I want to restore my database. I have a decrypted msgsql.db file. How to encrypt msgsql.db back to crypt14? Where is the public key stored on Whatsapp?

I have my private key, but the public key is used in encryption.

Comment: [whapas](https://github.com/B16f00t/whapa) whacipher claims to be able to encrypt .crypt14 files, but not .crypt15 files. Unfortunately the dev state that it needs "a encrypted database as reference to encrypt a new database".